# Setting Background For a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using fragments in my application, and I have to change the Background for one of the fragments within FragmnetTabs. For this very reason I am setting the `background` in the layout of that fragmnet, which I can see in `Graphical Layout` of `Eclipse` is working fine. But when I run my application it shows me Fragments content with black background, instead of the image I set. I am setting it this way...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/bg" >
<RelativeLayout/>
```

But this drwaable does not show up in the application. What could be the problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**

If I try to set the background in the following way, it works fine.

```
      android:background="@drawable:color/anycolor"
```

Why is it so that custom image is not getting shown up but android colour does?

Comment: @Marco the xml is same that I have posted. I mean it is not complete...but its of main layout in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this in code. Call on your `RelativeLayout`

`yourRelativeLayout.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.YourImage));`